# CNAME, htaccess and ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: .htaccess, cname-record

I have the following code to make sure that `api.example.com` will call `example.com/api.php`. It works on my localhost, but not on my website.

```
RewriteEngine On

 # Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^ api.php [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ website.php [L]
```

The browser returns the eror `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. Whats the problem and how do I fix this?

Comment: Show your DNS record(s)..

Comment: Have you tried clearing dns cache of the PC you are testing from? Try `ipconfig /flushdns` and also check your dns address.

Answer (score 0):

Try from another machine on another network. What does `host` return? Do you get the proper IP?

```
host api.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means that the problem has nothing to do with the server. It means that the bowser didn't even send any requests as it didn't find any `api.example.com` in the name records.

You have to open the account from which you purchased the domain name and find the settings where you can manage DNS records. And then you can either:

1. Point `anything.example.com` to your `example.com`. by adding wilcards to the name field of your type A record, such as `*.example.com` or:
2. Point only `api.example.com` to your `example.com` by a CNAME record `api` to `api.example.com`

And please note that changes in DNS records can sometimes take more than 24 hours to propagate. But usually it takes less than that.